Unable to open list button from related list in a modal popup
I have a list button that opens a screen flow.

However, I am unable to get the flow to open in a modal. It only opens in the same window which isn't a great UI experience since the flow doesn't have a way to exit the flow to return back to the account (original screen) if the user decides to exit out. Is there a way to have the list button open the flow (an action) in a separate window (modal). The list button behavior only shows existing window without or without header and sidebar.
What is the recommended approach to open a flow with an action on a lightning page tab with a single dynamic related list component?

Believe this article describes the solution that you seek.  https://hugolemos.medium.com/launch-flow-modal-from-a-related-list-00aba6590187

Thank you! That's what I was looking for! Works perfectly!
